# SP 2013 Enterprise: Where are all the services?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a 3 tier architecture, with 2 App, 2 WFE and 2 SQL in a cluster.

I began creating service applications on APP1 that also hosts Central Admin.  When I look at 'Services on Server' for APP1 and APP2, I'm not able to view or stop/start on APP1, but all the services are there on APP2 and WFE1/2.

Is it implied that all the servers are running on APP1 or am I missing something or done something wrong?  Any advice would be appreciated!

APP1
[image]

APP2
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your Screen shot, Looks like your farm is not properly configured.basically Microsoft SharePoint Foundation timer job is not giving you the option, this give me direction to check the couple of things.

- Check if the same thing for all WFE
- Make Sure PSConfig wizard is successfully Completed on All server in farm.
- Exaime the PSDig log and see if their is something you can find.
- make Sure the State Service is running.
- Under the Manage Server in the Farm, make sure no server need updates.
- what is the Config db version #

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was this item.  Thanks for the input!

* Make Sure PSConfig wizard is successfully Completed on All server in farm.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you used an enterprise key when you installed APP1? Also, it looks as though you may not have the appropriate permissions. It may be that you opened central administration from a normal IE session, or that you aren't using a farm administrator account. Try searching for and clicking the "SharePoint Central Administration"

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure I used the enterprise key for the APP and WFE servers.  I've RDPed to APP1 as one of two Farm admin accounts (also local admins), Opened Central Admin as Administrator, but I see the exact same thing.  I'm guessing your environment doesn't look like mine?

Comment: Is the account an administrator on every server in the farm as well as added as a farm administrator? Can you try another account? Can you try to disable UAC? Can you also check services.msc to see if the SharePoint Timer Service is running?

Comment: Yes, both accounts are local admins on each of the servers and are both Farm admins.  I've tried both accounts with the same results.  Timer service is running on each of the 4 servers.  You want me to just try to disable UAC on APP1?

Comment: Well, I just removed every server from the farm and wiped out all my DB's.  Setup the farm from a different server this time.  I had only used New-SPCentralAdministration rather than the Product Configuration Wizard, so I'm guessing that's probably where it went wrong.